# AngularJs: How to watch multiple collection using watchcollection

Tags: angularjs

In AngularJS I have 6 to 7 watchcollection that watches foo1,2,3...7 and all of them call the same method methodA().Is there any way in AngularJS to group all these watchers so that I dont have to write multiple separate watchcollection blocks.

```
$scope.$watchCollection(
                        "foo1",
                        function( newValue, oldValue ) {
                            methodA();
                        }
                );

$scope.$watchCollection(
                        "foo2",
                        function( newValue, oldValue ) {
                            methodA();
                        }
                );
```

............and similarly till foo7

Answer (score 0):

Yes. [watchGroup](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watchGroup).

```
$scope.$watchGroup(['foo1', 'foo2', ..., 'foo7'], 
    function(newValues, oldValues, scope) {
        methodA();  
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please do as shown below.

Here is nice video about [**$watchCollection**](https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-using-the-angularjs-scope-s-watchcollection-method)

```
$scope.$watchCollection('[foo1,foo2]', function () {
        methodA();
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, your code should look like this:

```
$scope.$watch('[foo1, foo2, foo3, foo4, foo5, foo6, foo7]', function() {
    methodA();
}, true);
```

Hope this helped.